# Google translate API For .Net Console Application

Tags: c#, google-translate

I'm creating a not-web application using C# and I would like to use Google translate API there. Is there a way to do this?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. [Here is an example](http://www.reimers.dk/blogs/jacob_reimers_weblog/archive/2008/06/18/using-google-s-translation-api-from-net.aspx).